# By creating an instance as an attribute, I can access to any method of the Car class from Electric Car class. Can anyone explain these in depth?

Tags: python, attributes, instance

```
class Car:
    def range(self):
        pass

class ElectricCar:
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model 
        self.car = Car()  # <--Explain this one!

electric_car = ElectricCar('Tesla')
electric_car.car.range()  # <---Calling method of Car class
```

By creating an instance as an attribute, I can access to any method of the Car class from Electric Car class. Can anyone explain these in depth?

Comment: That's kind of a weird design. It's like saying that an electric car is a non-car object with a regular car inside.

Comment: And electric cars have a model, but regular cars don't?

Comment: it was just a used as a reference, yup I do understand the car should have some parameter inside it. @user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same as how you created an instance of the class ElectricCar(). But you are creating the object for the class Car within another class. Therefore self.car is an instance of the class Car. 
So in order to call the method inside the class Car, you have to call it with
self.car.range() - here the self is referred to as the instance of the parent class(i.e. electric_car). So you call the range method as electric_car.car.range()

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for but your model is wierd